# Restricting access to certain views - Beginner

Tags: grails

I have a `Domain` class and `Controller` called `Person`. This `Controller` has 4 views. `create.gsp`, `remove.gsp`, `show.gsp`, `showdetail.gsp`.

What i want to do is to allows read permission for `showdetail.gsp` to all viewers and restrict access to `create.gsp`, `remove.gsp` and `show.gsp` views. Only the `Administrator` should be able to access these pages. How can i do this in Grails?

Comment: You can use [spring security core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) grails plugin. Plugin provides role based authentication. [Plugin's manual](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) can guide appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use security filters to do that or you can use Spring Security Core grails plugin. 
If you can want to use security filters, you can do the following:

1. Create session for each user at the time of login.
     session["user"] = "rohit"   // user name
2. Add security Filters:

   ```
    PersonFilters(controller: 'person', action: 'create') { 
       before = {
           // code to be change
           if(!session["user"]) {
         //flash.message = "Your session has been expired. Please login to continue."
               redirect(controller: "login", action:"index")
               return false;
          } else if(session["user"] && session["user"] != "admin"){
              // redirect to some action
              // redirect(controller: "", action:"index")
              return false;
          }
       }
   }
   ```

Similarly, you can add security filter for those actions that you don't want to show to any user except the admin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, user would need to login and after successful authentication, session should be maintained properly. And then in controller filter, you could write an interceptor which can allow access to certain actions based on authorization rules.

All these and much more is already done along with UI part in [nimble plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/nimble), it is very easy.

And read this document:
http://snimavat.github.io/nimble/guide/leverage.html#accesscontrol